# replacing Login URL to short URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have an URL as :

```
http://mydomain.com/site/?cmd=home
```

I want to change the above address to http://mydomain.com/home

i am using .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /site?cmd=$1 [L]
```

I am not sure where is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess and what URL did you use to test it?

Comment: For now i m on developer machine and url is: localhost:8080/site/?cmd=home   my .htaccess file is located on : E:\xampp\htdocs\site\.htaccess

Comment: And .htaccess is in DocumentRoot OR in a sub directory?

Comment: my site structure is as following: E:\xampp\htdocs\ => this is root while E:\xampp\htdocs\site this is the place where my website pages are located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rule works the other way around: you want to get from `/site/?cmd=home` to `/home`, but with your RewriteRule you are redirecting to `/site?cmd=` (Probably there is a mistake somewhere?)

If you want to redirect from `/site/?cmd=home` to `/home`, like the question states, use the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/site
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cmd=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/? [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /site\?cmd=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /site?cmd=$1 [L]
```